# Unable to to move to next page in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to loop through the pages and print the values for the table but it can't click the next button.

Error:

```
Selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: 
Element <a class="page-link"
href="javascript:move('generic-tokenholders2?a=0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1
745F52C74426C631bDD52&sid=&m=normal&s=16579517055253348798759097&p=2')"> 
is not clickable at point (1148,2553) because another element <div id="overlay"> 
obscures it`
```

Page: https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#balances

My Code:

```
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#balances")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
# num=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[3]/span/strong[2]").getText()
for i in range(1,20):
    time.sleep(5)
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"tokeholdersiframe")))
    print("udj")
    simpleTable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/table")
    rows = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"tr")
    for i in range(1,len(rows)):
            cols = rows[i].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"td")
            for g in cols:
                    print(g.text)
    next = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='d-inline-block']//a[@aria-label='Next']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",next)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-200);")
    next.click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Update:
Error pmadhu:
`

Comment: Please share the entire error stack trace

Comment: @HamzaAhmed Please be considerate when scraping websites, for example Etherscan offers a [robust, free API](https://etherscan.io/apis) that would probably serve your needs better than scraping their website.

Comment: It doesn't offer the function to scrape this data. I have already checked. @vtasca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe in the loop you are switching to a `iframe` performing some actions and clicking on `Next`.

When the 2nd page opened the scope is still on the previous page `iframe` and you are trying to find an `iframe` within that. Which is not the correct workflow.

You need to perform `switch_to.default_content()` after clicking on `Next` and then try to do the same on each page.

Below code did click on the `Next` without any exception:

```
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#balances")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(5)
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"tokeholdersiframe")))
    next = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='d-inline-block']//a[@aria-label='Next']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",next)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-200);")
    next.click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Please check update.

Comment: For which line you are getting that error?. Have you applied `scrollIntoView`

Comment: When i go to next.click().

Comment: @HamzaAhmed -  I ran the script you updated in the question. Sometimes the webpage gets stuck (not sure why) but sometime it worked for all the 20 pages without any exceptions. Better put the code in `try and except` block.

Comment: Same it gives exception, i'll do that.

Comment: any idea why it may go into timeout?